# Why do uname -p and uname -m and arch output different architectures?

Tags: macos, computer-architecture

On mountain lion (late 2010)

```
$ uname -p
i386
$ uname -m
x86_64
$ arch
i386
```

So i368 (32 bit) is my processor architecture, and x86_64 (64 bit) is my `machine hardware name` according to the uname man page. So why such results from uname and arch? And what exactly is `machine hardware name`?

Answer (score 12):

I found this link, [Re: Mac OS X Snow Leopard and 64-bit applications](http://lists.apple.com/archives/Darwin-dev/2009/Aug/msg00211.html),
which says:

> `arch` and `uname -p` both return the processor family type, i386. (as opposed to ppc or arm.)  I think the rationale was that too many scripts depend upon this behavior.
>
> `uname -m` tells you which slice of xnu you booted from, i.e. x86_64 for the 64 bit kernel, i386 for the 32 bit kernel.
>
> It's unfortunate that the phrase i386 has two meanings.

This clarifies the issue.