# Why the architecture of my Mac is i386?

Tags: linux, mac

My Macbook Pro is 15", latest version. Today I open the Terminal and typed the command `uname -p`, the result surprised me: `i386`. We all know that the processor of the MBP 15" is Intel's i7, but why the result of the command is i386? Just because the command uname is a linux command? Or it's real architecture is i386?

Comment: Seems that this one is better [Why does my Mac OS X 10.6 kernel run in 32-bit mode?](http://superuser.com/questions/23214/why-does-my-mac-os-x-10-6-kernel-run-in-32-bit-mode). Thank you Nelson.

Comment: That is not a duplicate, since the kernel mode is irrelevant to what `uname -p` prints. Also, the kernel has been 64-bit only since 10.8, so OP is almost certainly running under a 64-bit kernel. [Why do uname -p and uname -m and arch output different architectures?](http://superuser.com/questions/835514/why-do-uname-p-and-uname-m-and-arch-output-different-architectures) is a much closer match.

Answer (score -2):

That's because your os is running under 32-bit mode (i386) and not 64-bit mode.

Comment: More specifically – if I remember correctly, *userspace* runs in 32-bit mode, although the kernel is 64-bit.

Comment: And vice versa, you can run 64-bit programs on a 32-bit kernel.

Comment: This is incorrect. OS X's kernel and most of its userspace have been 64-bit-only since version 10.8 (and was mostly 64-bit-capable on supported hardware in 10.6 and 10.7). OS X's version of `uname -p` printing "i386" does not in any way indicate that anything is running -- or even is capable of running -- in 32-bit mode.